# How to bind the value and event handler of a custom ionic angular component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using ion-datetime in ionic/angular so the user can set a date in my app. But I'm in Brazil, so I have to set the atributes to change the texts used in the component:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY"
                monthShortNames="Jan, Fev, Mar, Abr, Mai, Jun, Jul, Ago, Set, Out, Nov, Dez"
                doneText="Selecionar"
                cancelText="Cancelar" 
                [(ngModel)]="myProperty" name="data"
                (ionChange)="myChangeHandler();">
</ion-datetime>
```

This is working fine, but I'd like to create a custom component to centralize this configuration in one place. So instead of above code I'd like to use:

```
<my-datetime [(ngModel)]="myProperty" name="data"
             (ionChange)="myChangeHandler();">  </my-datetime/>
```

I know how I can create a custom component to declare the ion-datetime, but my doubt is how to 'redirect' the bindings made to the custom component, the model property and change event to the inner ion-datetime.

Comment: Hi, Did you try with the @Input() and @Output() decorators?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Input()` and `@Output()` from `@angular/core` for this

```
<my-datetime [property]="myProperty" name="data"
         (dateSelected)="myChangeHandler();">  </my-datetime/>
```

And then in the my datetime component

```
@Input() property: any = '';
@Output() readonly dateSelected= new EventEmitter<any>();
```

And on selection of date emit the event like

```
 this.dateSelected.emit(your selected date);
```

The emit will call myChangeHandler in the parent component

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) is the details guide on these decorators, you can follow this for more info.